# How to access WP REST API via OAuth by using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, oauth

I can't figure out how to access Wordpress via REST API with OAuth.
My App is made by Ruby on Rails. So I'd like to use RoR 5.1.
My objective is to get all post from the api.
As far as I check, no appropriate gem is there.

Anyone help please.

Answer (score 1):

**In Rails the common gem to deal with OAuth is OmniAuth.**

**1)** If you did your authentication system based on Devise then you have an easy way to add OAuth to your app.

**Here a good example to connect to Facebook API with Devise:**

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

**Here the gem to connect with WordPress:**

https://github.com/jwickard/omniauth-wordpress-oauth2-plugin

**2)** If you didn't your authentication system with Devise then check the OmniAuth documentation to add it to your app:
https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth

And of course you will use the WordPress gem to add the strategy as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Before that, I'm trying not to use devise for integration to wordpress site. For that reason, I just want to connect it by using OAuth authentication. BTW, it seems like there's no wordpress gem as far as I checked.

Comment: You can use OmniAuth gem without using Devise, this way you can use the wordpress gem combined with OmniAuth.

Comment: I see. Let me check it later. Thanks.

Comment: https://medium.com/@kaileegray/adding-omniauth-to-rails-web-app-2491392787fa this must help, try to use wordpress-omniath help instead of facebook

Comment: I examined the document a while ago, though, it must be for Facebook app. Do you have any sample for wordpress?

Comment: https://github.com/zachfeldman/rubypress with this gem and this documentation  https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API i'm sure you can accomplish your things